# Infinite scrolling on a sprite(Parallax)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, parallax

I am a newbie to the world of cocos2d i am developing my first tutorial and facing one problem
my problem is i have an image (1024 X 320) and my orientation is landscape i need to move that image continuously from right to left for this purpose i have used space shooter tutorial by Ray(Thanks to him) but the image doesn't seem to be appearing again and again.
my code is..

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        // 1) Create the CCParallaxNode
        backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
        [self addChild:backgroundNode z:-1];

        // 2) Create the sprites we'll add to the CCParallaxNode
        Back = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
        //Back.position=ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        Back.rotation = -90;
        Back1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
        Back1.rotation = -90;

        // 3) Determine relative movement speeds for space dust and background
        CGPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);

        // 4) Add children to CCParallaxNode
        [backgroundNode addChild:Back z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
        NSLog(@"back.content width is...%f",Back.contentSize.width);
        [backgroundNode addChild:Back1 z:1 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height*2)];

        // 5) Enable updates
        [self scheduleUpdate]; 
}
    return self;
}


- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    // 1) Update background position
    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(0,-1000);
    backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));

    // 2) Check for background elements moving offscreen
    NSArray *spaceDusts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Back, Back1, nil];
    for (CCSprite *spaceDust in spaceDusts) {
        if ([backgroundNode convertToWorldSpace:spaceDust.position].x < -spaceDust.contentSize.width) {
            [backgroundNode incrementOffset:ccp(2*spaceDust.contentSize.width,0) forChild:spaceDust];
        }
    }
}
```

please help me out of this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
if (backgroundNode.position.y <-screenSize.height*2)
            backgroundNode.position = ccp(0,0);
```

As init method is called only once the approach you are doing will be done only one time you need to again set the Position of the backgroundNode to 0 in your update method.
here the multiple may vary

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is creating a paralax moving from bottom to top change CGPointMake(0, 1.0) to this CGPointMake(1.0,0) in paraNode addChild line.

```
-(id) init
 {
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
if( (self=[super init]) )
{
    float yPos =0.0;
    NSMutableString *fileNameString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    if (IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        [fileNameString appendString:@"Background-568h.png"];
        yPos= 560.0;
    }
    else
    {
        [fileNameString appendString:@"Background.png"];
        yPos= 470.0;
    }
    background1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileNameString];
    background1.tag = 1;
    background1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

    background2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileNameString];
    background2.tag = 2;
    background2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

    background3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileNameString];
    background3.tag = 3;
    background3.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

    background4 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileNameString];
    background4.tag = 4;
    background4.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);


    paraNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
    [paraNode addChild:background1 z:1 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(0, 1.0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [paraNode addChild:background2 z:2 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(0, 1.0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, -yPos)];
    [paraNode addChild:background3 z:3 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(0, 1.0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, -yPos*2)];
    [paraNode addChild:background4 z:4 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(0, 1.0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, -yPos*3)];



    [self addChild:paraNode z:-1 tag:123];
    [self updateFrameRate:0.7 andYposition:yPos];

    [fileNameString release];
    fileNameString = nil;
}
return self;
 }

 -(void)updateFrameRate:(float)speedValue andYposition:(float)yposToSet
 {

   move1 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:speedValue position:CGPointMake(0, yposToSet)];
   move2 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.0 position:CGPointMake(0, -yposToSet)];
   move3 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.0 position:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
   CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:move1,move2,move3, nil];
   CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];
   [paraNode runAction:repeat];

}
```